# Get text from javascript alert box in vb.net with user32.dll

Tags: javascript, .net, api, interop, user32

Hy guys!

Please help me out;

I'm trying to get the text from an javascript alert box with user32.dll API but i can't figure out the lpszClass name.

Please someone help me out and sorry if it's a dumb question.

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(hwndParent As IntPtr, hwndChildAfter As IntPtr, lpszClass As String, lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="FindWindow", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function FindWindow(lpClassName As String, lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As UInt32, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowTextLength(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Private Function Form1_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Deactivate As String
    Dim hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow("#32770", "Mensagem da página da web")

    'hwnd = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "<NEED TO KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE", Nothing)


    Dim length As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder("", length + 1)
    GetWindowText(hwnd, sb, sb.Capacity)
   return sb.ToString()

End Function
```

Comment: So you're trying to write a program that gets the text of a window created by another program (the browser in this case)?

Comment: p.s. your code formatting is a bit off

Comment: Yep. Exactly.My application uses a WebBrowser Control to do some stuff in a web page. But some alerts pops up and I need to get the text messages to handle'em. So i cant figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Fellow Windows API noob here, but here's how I did something similar:

VisualStudio comes with a tool called Spy++ (it's under the Tools menu) that lists every "window" on the system along with the relevant information. The information you are looking for is shown right after the window title:

[image: Spy++]

In my case, I needed to find multiple children with the same class, so I ended up using the EnumChildWindows function instead of FindWindowEx. Here's my code in Java (using JNA):

```
User32 u32 = User32.INSTANCE;
WinDef.HWND window = u32.FindWindow("#32770", "Control Center Login");
List<WinDef.HWND> windows = new ArrayList<>();
u32.EnumChildWindows(window, (child, data) -> {
    char[] name = new char[256];
    u32.GetClassName(child, name, 256);
    String nameStr = new String(name).trim();
     if(nameStr.equals("Edit")) {
        windows.add(child);
    }
    return true;
}, null);
```

I hope you have not been waiting for this answer for the past 2 years, but if someone else finds this question, here's a way to do it :)